# Applying a negative skew has no effect on the inner HTML

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a id="unskew" href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a id="unskew" href="">Prices</a></li>
            <li><a id="unskew" href="">About Me</a></li>
            <li><a id="unskew" href="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>`
```

I'm attempting to use negative skew to straighten up the text but it just is not changing even when I use just the negative skew by itself it does nothing.

```
#unskew
{
    -webkit-transform: skew(-10deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-10deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-10deg);
    transform: skew(-10deg);
}

ul li  
{
    transform: skew(10deg);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [**CSS Transforms Module Level 1**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#terminology)
>
> A transformable element is an element whose layout is governed by the CSS box model which is either a block-level or [atomic inline-level element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#x13), or whose display property computes to table-row, table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-cell, or table-caption.

The anchor elements are `inline` by default, thus the skew transformation isn't applied.

You could change the `display` of the anchor elements to `inline-block`. In doing so, the skew transformation will be applied.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/20sgrm3u/1/)

```
#unskew {
    -webkit-transform: skew(-10deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-10deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-10deg);
    transform: skew(-10deg);
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Side note:

- As [Jonathon points out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28652749/applying-a-negative-skew-has-no-effect-on-the-inner-html/28652784#comment45602628_28652784), you should use classes rather than `id`s, since `id`s must be unique and should not be duplicated..

Comment: Also, consider getting rid of duplicated IDs and using classes: http://jsfiddle.net/20sgrm3u/1/

Comment: @BrandonKorenek If you mark this as the answer it'll be easier for others looking at this question later.

Comment: @Jonathan Marked! Sorry been a while since I've been on XD